# ReactJS application is not working with IE

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, browser

Reactjs application is not working with IE

Below I have shown files where I have added solution for react-app-polyfill,

**Package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "^1.6.12",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "fontsource-roboto": "^2.1.4",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.2.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.22.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },

"browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "ie 11",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "ie 11",
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
```

**Index.js**

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
```

while I check in IE It gives me below error,

```
  DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
```

Please help me to solve this,

I will appreciate best answer.

Comment: I can see that you have added the polyfills. I suggest you install `core-JS` using the command `npm install core-js` and add `import 'core-js/stable'` on the first line  (above polyfills for IE browser) in the `index.js` file. Save the changes. After that try to delete the `.cache` folder under `node_modules` and try to run the project. See whether it helps to run the project in the IE 11 browser.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but this solution also didn't work

Comment: You have provided very limited information. Please try to inform us, which exact version of the IE browser you are using? is it a newly created project or you have already added some functionality to it? If you have added some functionality then provide detailed information about it. Does the project work on other browsers? If possible, try to provide detailed steps with a sample code to reproduce the issue. After adding the core-js, did you get any new errors or the same error persist?

Comment: I have added functionality to reactJS . My IE version is 11, yes this application is working in other all bowser but not working in IE.

Comment: I am using rest Apis to get data in application

Comment: rest Apis developed in PHP with laravel framework

Comment: Actually what you are seeing in the console is a warning, not an error. the issue is app is not loading in the IE browser. At this stage, it is hard for us to say what exactly causes this issue. To narrow down the issue, you can try to check whether you are able to load the newly created app in the IE or not. after loading it successfully, you can try to add functionalities/third-party libraries one by one and try to check the result in IE at each step can help to find the problematic thing.