# ReactJS+ IE+ Function expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

Reactjs application is not working on IE11

Please find my package.json and index.js file below,

index.js file :

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9';
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
import 'core-js/stable';
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
import 'intersection-observer';
//import 'isomorphic-fetch';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
```

package.json file :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "^1.6.12",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "core-js": "^3.9.0",
    "fontsource-roboto": "^2.1.4",
    "intersection-observer": "^0.12.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.2.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.22.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all",
      "ie >=9"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version",
      "ie 11"
    ]
  },
```

It gives below error,

[image]

While check in debugger it shows like below,

[image]
Please help me to resolve this issue,

I will appreciate best answer.

Comment: Here, I want to confirm with you whether this thread is about the same issue that you had posted in recent days? [Thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66038742/reactjs-application-is-not-working-with-ie), [Thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66285127/reactjs-application-not-working-on-ie11-gives-object-error). If yes, I suggest you do not create duplicate threads for the same issue and try to carry on the discussion on the previous threads. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: If you mean that this is a different issue than for testing purposes, I would suggest you remove `import 'core-js/stable';` from `index.js` file and see whether it makes any difference. If the issue persists then please try to check whether you are getting any new errors and also try to provide more information about this issue. If possible, provide detailed steps and sample code for reproducing the issue. Thanks for your understanding.